# j2me polish , xmpp

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

i created my own chat application using j2me polish (netbeans IDE) i designed a chat screen using framed form and added a textfield with direct input property, and when sending '&' symbol, the connection closes immediately....
any ideas please..
btw i am using openfire 3.6.4

Answer (score 2):

Look for an error message in the XML stream from the server. If the server is closing the connection it should give you an error message for why. The most likely reason is that you're not escaping XML reserved characters ('&' is a reserved character) in the message text and the server detects the improperly formatted XML and closes the connection.